# Instructor led training for SPfx and SharePoint PnP?

Tags: spfx, training, office-ui-fabric

Does anyone know of instructor led training for working with SPfx and SharePoint PnP/Office UI Fabric?

I'm looking to get a jump on SharePoint Online development.

Comment: lookup Mastering the SharePoint Framework Course - by Andrew Connell

Comment: Have a look at the youtube channel here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_mKdhw-V6CeCM7gTo_Iy7w?pbjreload=10 - Not instructor led, but covers the basics.

Comment: @Aveenav Andrew Connell has some great options.  Not only does he provide live training, he has recorded sessions available to refer to as well. Thanks for the suggestion.